# SharePoint Sanity Testing In New Domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, domain, testing

We're completing a domain migration and trying to compile a set of sanity checks/tests to validate the move for various applications including SharePoint.

There is not requirement yet to do full functional testing of all applications built on SharePoint.

Does anybody have a list of basic sanity checks that would be performed to validate a SharePoint Farm moved to a new domain and also users moved to that domain?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think, their is such list available. But i can share my experience.

- Make sure all service started(which you are using)
- Test the User Profile Sync, run the full sync and test if import all users.
- Test the Search Service
- Test all the web apps are up and running( account changed for the app Pool).
- ask couple of customer, login to the sharepoint and test if their stuff working i.e authentication, permission etc.
- Run the workflow.
- check the ULS logs, event log for any critical error.
- make sure all the content DBs are update and available.

Comment: Because the user accounts will be migrated too (using Move-SPUser) are there any further tests I need to do from user accounts?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned....ask couple of user to test their permission and access etc on new farm.